# Anything to do with JQuery's $(window) isn't firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

It seems I'm doing something wrong with JQuery's $(window) object in IE8 because it doesn't fire off when I bind things to it, when I try to get data from it, or when I bind resize/scroll.

This is ALL the JavaScript code I have on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind("load", function() {
            var footerBottom = 0;
            positionFooter();

            function positionFooter() {

                footerBottom = -$(window).scrollTop();
                console.log("footer bottom: " + footerBottom);
                $("#footerbar").css({ bottom: footerBottom + "px" });
            }

            $(window)
                .scroll(positionFooter)
                .resize(positionFooter)

        });
        </script>
```

So why isn't IE8 doing any of that?

edit: removed site link, so as to not be a spammer.

Comment: .scrollTop() doesn't work in IE8. At least that what most of the comments on jQuery's website say. http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html was suggested as a solution for IE8

Comment: So how should I get that value?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Have a sticky footer that's always at the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to make a sticky footer. You can do all this with CSS.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mUux/)

*The important part is `position:fixed`*

Comment: wrapping it in $(document).ready (with function correctly spelled) didn't work. tried it with html, window, and document being bound instead of window as shown in your code, and none of them worked.

Comment: Edited. Try it again. Can you post a fiddle or the site itself by the way to make it easier?

Comment: Awesome, I completely forgot about position: fixed. Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The `$(window)` object is buggy in IE8 and Opera, try using `$(document)` instead.

```
$(document).bind("load",
```

or `$(html)`

```
$(html).bind("load",
```

Comment: I tried binding to html, and document, but that didn't work. Even tried wrapping it all in $(document).ready, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Try `jQuery(document)` instead of `$(document)`

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MJYGA/ It seems to work there, but on the site linked it does not, even though it's the same code. I also used the same JQuery version.

Comment: Some other script is interfering with it then. Remove additional scripts one-by-one until it works.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong, it only seems like it's working because there's no content beyond 100% of the viewing window. No scroll bar. Also there are no other scripts in the site.